# Java - repaint() method is called once then it doesn't show anything

Tags: java, swing, repaint

I've been trying to get a n-ary tree structure graphed so when I enter some node it shows up but it doesn't.

It only draws the root then it "deletes" everything.

Here's my code:

```
public LinkedList<Node> nodes;
public Tree tree;

public TreeViewer() {

    initComponents();
    this.nodes = new LinkedList<>();
}

@Override
public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
    super.paintComponent(g); //To change body of generated methods, choose Tools | Templates.

    if (this.tree != null) {
        this.checkTree(this.tree.getRoot(), g, 200, 20, 20, 20);
    }else{
        System.out.println("empty");
    }
}

public void checkTree(Node current, Graphics g, int x, int y, int height, int width) {

    current.setX(x);
    current.setY(y);
    current.setHeight(height);
    current.setWidth(width);

    if (!this.nodes.contains(current)) {
        g.drawString(current.name, x, y);
        g.setColor(Color.black);
        this.nodes.add(current);

        if (current.getSon() != null && current.getBrother() == null) {
            this.checkTree(current.getSon(), g, x, y + 40, height, width);

        } else if (current.getBrother() != null && current.getSon() == null) {
            this.checkTree(current.getBrother(), g, x - 30, y, height, width);

        } else if (current.getBrother() != null && current.getSon() != null) {
            this.checkTree(current.getSon(), g, x, y + 40, height, width);
            this.checkTree(current.getBrother(), g, x - 30, y, height, width);
        }
    }
}
```

and I'm adding the nodes trought a button, here's the code:

```
private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
    if(this.modificator.getTree() == null){
        Node current = new Node(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Type root ID:"));
        this.modificator.setTree( new Tree(current));

    }else{
        Node current = new Node(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Type ID:"));
        this.modificator.getTree().addSon(this.modificator.getTree().getRoot(), this.modificator.getTree().getRoot(), current);

    }
    this.modificator.repaint();
}
```

So my problem resides in whenever I call repaint() after the first time, all that was drawn (only the root) gets "erased" from the panel.

Comment: When I draw a pre-instanced tree, it works, but I need it to draw it while I'm adding nodes at any moment of the running.

Comment: @CameronSkinner Ah...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Inside `checkTree` you have this:

```
if (!this.nodes.contains(current))
```

Presumably this is intended to handle cycles in your graph, but I don't see anywhere that clears `this.nodes`. That means that on the second call to `paintComponent` you immediately bail out of `checkTree` because the root has already been added to `this.nodes`.

If you clear out `this.nodes` at the end of `paintComponent` that might do the trick.